# time stamp on a button google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, button, time, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a button that will only be visible when a specific cell is empty. if the cell is empty and the button is pressed it will add date and time to that specific cell. my question is, is it possible to let the button check 1 row below when time has passed 4 am so in place of checking cell B2 it will check B3
this is my current code:

```
    function doGet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('key');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('klant');
  var klant = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  Logger.log(klant)


  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Gym Check In');
  var grid = app.createFlexTable().setId('grid');
  app.add(grid);

  var row = 0;
  var column = 0;
  var enable=false;

  for (var m in klant) {    

    grid.setWidget(row, 0, app.createLabel(klant[m]));

    if(sheet.getRange('G2').getValue()==''){enable=true}
      grid.setWidget(row, 1, app.createButton('Check In').setEnabled(enable).setId(row+2).addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler('checkIn').addCallbackElement(grid)).addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setEnabled(false)));}
  if(!enable){grid.setWidget(row, 1, app.createHTML('<b>Error:</b>'));}
  return app;
}

function checkIn(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('key');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('klant');

  var button = e.parameter.source;

  sheet.getRange(button, 7).setValue(new Date());
  sheet.getRange(button, 8).setValue(Session.getActiveUser());    
}
```

Comment: Once again you say "visible" and you use "visible" in your code ...which one  finally?  :-)   Beside that, this would be quite easy using a second IF statement that looks at the current time of day.

Comment: i can't find the word "visible" in my code so i don't understand what you mean. and can you give me a sample code on how to use specific time in a if statement. thanks

Comment: Your post begins with: ** I have a button that will only be visible when a...** and your code use enabled ...(sorry I made a typo in my comment, not important...) and I will suggest a code sample with an example as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few errors and typos in your sample code, I've set up a new version that uses only one server handler (no need to create one for each button since they all call the same handler function) and one client handler (for the same reason : same effect on source).

Then you forgot to increment row and to reset enable to false after each iteration .

I added the date comparison too using a simple getHours() javascript method (see [doc on date object here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp))

Here is the full code, I hope it's clear enough... if not, don't hesitate to come back here .

```
function doGet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Zfs3LnVYx2JzaZvasdyQek6_FnqelO95VLrKH8gconA');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('klant');
  var klant = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getMaxRows(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var headers = klant.shift();
  Logger.log(headers);
  Logger.log(klant);
  var time = new Date().getHours();
  Logger.log(time);
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Gym Check In');
  var grid = app.createFlexTable().setId('grid').setStyleAttributes({'marginLeft':'60px'});
  app.add(grid);

  var row = 0;
  var column = 0;
  var enable=false;
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('checkIn').addCallbackElement(grid); 
  var cHandler = app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setEnabled(false)
  for (var m=0 ; m<klant.length-1 ; m++) {  
    Logger.log('value in col 7 and row '+m+' = '+klant[m][6]);
    grid.setWidget(row, 0, app.createLabel(klant[m][0]));
    if(time<4){    
      if(klant[Number(m)+1][6]=='' ){enable=true}
    }else{
      Logger.log(Number(m)+1)
      if(klant[Number(m)+1][6]=='' ){enable=true}
    }
    grid.setWidget(row, 1, app.createButton('Check In').setEnabled(enable).setId(row+2).addClickHandler(handler).addClickHandler(cHandler));

    if(!enable){grid.setWidget(row, 1, app.createHTML('<b>Error:</b>'));}
    row++;
    enable=false;
  }
  return app;
}

function checkIn(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Zfs3LnVYx2JzaZvasdyQek6_FnqelO95VLrKH8gconA');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('klant');

  var button = e.parameter.source;

  sheet.getRange(button, 7).setValue(new Date());
  sheet.getRange(button, 8).setValue(Session.getActiveUser());    
}
```

Comment: first thanks for your help. the app doesn't work right. in dev mode you get an empty page if you only have one row of data and in exec mode it show the button, but when you press it it doesn't add the active user and the date is added in the wrong place.

Comment: Forgot to mention that you should of course reset the SS ID to I your value. Please check hat you copied the code exactly. I tested it and I'm positive when I say it does work .

Comment: the meaning of the document is that it contains 1 customer and every time the customer visits one of my places one of my employees has to run the app and press the button after that the app will log the date and the user that pressed the button. the customer can only vist my place for once a day and because the place is open till 4 am the app can only log the next check in if it has passed 4 am. i hope it is more clear on what the app should do and maybe handy if you have my test document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsVcdkfSriMvdDNWd0NmZ3JWZVRjMjhMSGsybHlRbVE&usp=sharing

Comment: I'll share my sheet with you so you can check that it is working.

Comment: It look like that my sheet is broken :) currently i can only test the first options and those are working i have to wait till tomorrow to see if the time function is working too. thanks a lot

Comment: ?? you could test it by simply changing the time value to another value ;) btw, I changed a few details to suit your specific use case.

Comment: other comment : I suppose your sheet is not going to be empty at start ? it changes of course the way we can define the useful range... now I used getMaxRows, this mean I don't care if rows are empty but it created an Ui with 1000 rows by default since I use neww spreadsheets. This is probably not the idea but you were testing like that so I adapted myself!!